# Por que me aparece error en el cargue de archivos al ejecutar aplicación

Tags: php, mysqli

Agradezco su colaboración anticipada por favor con el siguiente inconveniente en Php con Visual Studio Code

Estoy corriendo una aplicación en visual studio code (el archivo index.php)

en las variables de entorno tengo configurados:

variables de entorno para el usuario:
C:\wamp\php

variables de entorno del sistema:

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3

Dentro del símbolo del sistema pongo php -v

C:\Users\hecamava>php -v

Y me aparece los siguientes errores:
Failed loading C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
Failed loading C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\php_xdebug.dll
PHP 5.4.3 (cli) (built: May 15 2012 01:01:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Vale mencionar que dentro de la ubicación C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\

Si tengo el archivo php_xdebug.dll, no se porque no me aparece esa falla en el cmd.

Luego procedo acorrer el programa en visual studio code, pero me sigue apareciendo el error:

"php" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

en vista de esto:

1.

Será que es de suma importancia que el archivo php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll este dentro de la carpeta
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext?, vale mencionar que he buscado dicho controlador pero no ve de donde descargarlo.

2 por que razón me muestra error al cargar el archivo php_xdebug.dll, ya que esta dentro de la carpeta correspondiente?

Muchas gracias por su colaboración

Comment: ¿Estas tratando de correr una lib diseñada para PHP 7.2 en PHP 5.4.3? Cuando estas en Apache, usar las librerías TS. NTS es para IIS, o si es para ejecutar por consola, verificar si fue compilado TS o NTS. Si es el PHP de xampp es TS seguro. Descargar el módulo correcto para tu PHP [acá](https://xdebug.org/download/historical). Sugiero actualizar tu código y el Xampp a mínimo PHP 7.4, preferiblemente PHP 8.

Comment: Otra cosa, es que si la aplicación no está usando la librería php_xdebug-xxx, puedes deshabilitarla en `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini` y ya te ahorras mi comentario anterior.

Comment: Hola gracias,estoy trabajando wampp server con la siguiente configuracion Apache: 2.4.2, MySQL: 5.5.24, Php: 5.4.3, PHPMyAdmin 3.5.1, SqlBuddy 1.3.3 XDebug: 2.2.0

Comment: cordial saludo aeportugal, acabo de realizar lo siguiente que permite actualizar la versión php a una mas reciente (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hf-JoSG7P3U&t=44s) pero al momento de iniciar el wampp server me queda en naranja y ya no me deja ejecutar las demás paginas que tengo en php.